# How to solve clique is not defined error?

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-authority, poa

I have going a PoA network, and everything looks like it works. But I cannot get clique to show up in geth.

```
> clique
ReferenceError: 'clique' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Has anyone any idea about the cause of this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate you question? How to recreate the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing geth folder from the data folder. Then re-initialise genesis.json to data folder. If your data folder is node1/

```
geth --datadir node1/ init genesis.json
```

Test you setup after running the node using geth. Connect to ipc

```
geth attach ipc:node1/geth.ipc
```

Check clique after successful connection. Please make sure geth.ipc is there in node1/ folder

Answer (score 0):

It needs IPC on the geth connection.